# Angular CLI karma tests not running

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, karma-runner, angular-cli

I have an Angular2 project, created with Angular Cli 1.0.0.rc2

When I run `ng test`, the project builds (without errors!), karma launches chrome and displays

"Karma v1.4.1 - connected" and

"Chrome 56.0.2924 (Mac OS X 10.12.3) is idle"

Soon after, I get an error in the console saying
`You need to include some adapter that implements __karma__.start method!`

Funny part is that the `test.ts` that is called to start the test is actually running (confirmed with console.log('test')) and it does have a `__karma__.start()` call.

Anyone can help?

I'm using Node 6.10.0 and NPM 3.10.10.

For reference, here's the `test.ts` file that karma calls, I haven't changed anything but the `console.log()` at the end:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

// Unfortunately there's no typing for the `__karma__` variable. Just declare it as any.
declare var __karma__: any;
declare var require: any;

// Prevent Karma from running prematurely.
__karma__.loaded = function () {};

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
let context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
// Finally, start Karma to run the tests.
__karma__.start();
console.log('test started');
```

And the `karma.conf.js`:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
      ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
      : ['progress','kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

**EDIT 1**

Karma is run from the root folder, the folder structure below looks like this:

```
<-- root
   -- src/
      -- karma.conf.js
      -- .angular-cli.json
      -- package.json
      -- protractor.conf.js
      -- tsconfig.json
      -- tslint.json
      -- typings.json
      -- app/
         -- index.html
         -- main.ts
         -- polyfills.ts
         -- test.ts         <--- this is called by karma
         -- tsconfig.app.json
         -- tsconfig.spec.json
         -- classes/
         -- components/
            -- some-component/
               -- some.component.ts
               -- some.component.spec.ts
               -- some.component.html
               -- some.component.css
         -- confjs/
         -- guards/
         -- interfaces/
         -- models/
         -- routes/
         -- services/
```

**EDIT 2**

I created a new blank project with the standard configuration, and when running `ng test` it is running successfully with the 3 specs that angular cli provides for the `app.component.ts`

Since I did not change anything about the configuration of karma, test files or anything else, the question is why aren't the tests in my real project running?

At least the specs for the `app.component.ts` should run, since the file is in the same place as in my test project. There might be issues with karma not being able to find other spec files, but that one should run at a minimum.

**EDIT 3**

I also noticed that after upgrading to Angular CLI rc2, the console.log() message is not executed anymore.

**EDIT 4**

I finally figured out how to get more information from karma :D Sadly it doesn't seem to show much more, than I already know. Except that I can see that the `app` folder doesn't seem to be watched. Only `src/test.ts` and `src/assets/` second of which obviously doesn't include any test files or specs.

Here's the log (I quitted manually at the end):

```
16 03 2017 20:49:40.709:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inlined plugin (defining framework:jasmine).
16 03 2017 20:49:40.712:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inlined plugin (defining launcher:Chrome, launcher:ChromeCanary, launcher:Chromium, launcher:Dartium, test).
16 03 2017 20:49:40.712:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inlined plugin (defining framework:@angular/cli, preprocessor:@angular/cli, webpackPlugin, preprocessor:webpack, middleware:webpackBlocker, preprocessor:sourcemap).
16 03 2017 20:49:40.712:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inlined plugin (defining reporter:kjhtml).
16 03 2017 20:49:40.712:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inlined plugin (defining reporter:coverage-istanbul).
16 03 2017 20:49:42.821:DEBUG [web-server]: Instantiating middleware
16 03 2017 20:49:42.829:DEBUG [reporter]: Trying to load reporter: kjhtml
16 03 2017 20:49:42.830:DEBUG [reporter]: Trying to load color-version of reporter: kjhtml (kjhtml_color)
16 03 2017 20:49:42.830:DEBUG [reporter]: Couldn't load color-version.
16 03 2017 20:50:26.799:DEBUG [preprocessor.sourcemap]: base64-encoded source map for /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/polyfills.ts
16 03 2017 20:50:26.872:DEBUG [preprocessor.sourcemap]: base64-encoded source map for /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/test.ts
16 03 2017 20:50:27.093:DEBUG [karma]: List of files has changed, trying to execute
16 03 2017 20:50:27.094:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
16 03 2017 20:50:27.196:DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "/Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/polyfills.ts"
16 03 2017 20:50:27.197:DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "/Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets"
16 03 2017 20:50:27.206:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.4.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
16 03 2017 20:50:27.206:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
16 03 2017 20:50:27.325:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
16 03 2017 20:50:27.326:DEBUG [temp-dir]: Creating temp dir at /var/folders/jb/ckmrwnyj6sl2gqvbzq28l9x40000gn/T/karma-26134570
16 03 2017 20:50:27.327:DEBUG [launcher]: /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome --user-data-dir=/var/folders/jb/ckmrwnyj6sl2gqvbzq28l9x40000gn/T/karma-26134570 --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --disable-default-apps --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-device-discovery-notifications http://localhost:9876/?id=26134570
16 03 2017 20:50:29.444:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/node_modules/karma/static/client.html
16 03 2017 20:50:29.962:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/node_modules/karma/static/karma.js
16 03 2017 20:50:30.129:DEBUG [karma]: A browser has connected on socket slzc36ToAi1EBjsoAAAA
16 03 2017 20:50:30.330:DEBUG [web-server]: upgrade /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=slzc36ToAi1EBjsoAAAA
16 03 2017 20:50:30.330:DEBUG [proxy]: NOT upgrading proxyWebSocketRequest /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=slzc36ToAi1EBjsoAAAA
16 03 2017 20:50:30.441:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/node_modules/karma/static/favicon.ico
16 03 2017 20:50:30.478:INFO [Chrome 56.0.2924 (Mac OS X 10.12.3)]: Connected on socket slzc36ToAi1EBjsoAAAA with id 26134570
16 03 2017 20:50:30.479:DEBUG [launcher]: Chrome (id 26134570) captured in 3.272 secs
16 03 2017 20:50:30.479:DEBUG [karma]: All browsers are ready, executing
16 03 2017 20:50:30.480:DEBUG [karma]: Captured 1 browsers
16 03 2017 20:50:30.631:DEBUG [middleware:karma]: custom files null null
16 03 2017 20:50:30.631:DEBUG [middleware:karma]: Serving static request /context.html
16 03 2017 20:50:31.028:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/node_modules/karma/static/context.html
16 03 2017 20:50:31.705:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/src/polyfills.ts?f7f84cb0226c1ac1d1ea181f87f1b945c7b60bf5 /
16 03 2017 20:50:31.706:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/polyfills.ts
16 03 2017 20:50:31.706:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/src/assets/cmp/respond.min.js?a38264053571de02291899eabf9ae749c9a1159c /
16 03 2017 20:50:31.706:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/respond.min.js
16 03 2017 20:50:31.721:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/polyfills.ts
16 03 2017 20:50:31.739:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/respond.min.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.258:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/src/assets/cmp/excanvas.min.js?ae4ce1a2bfb06c82653633191b04a8969a946b6b /
16 03 2017 20:50:32.258:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/excanvas.min.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.258:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/src/assets/cmp/jquery/dist/jquery.js?38e82b4f24bf9f7e678a1d69a4e635363ce711ab /
16 03 2017 20:50:32.258:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/jquery/dist/jquery.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.258:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/src/assets/cmp/raphael.min.js?4854da2d86626159d5015ed6ad6c142b70c2b370 /
16 03 2017 20:50:32.258:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/raphael.min.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.271:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/excanvas.min.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.290:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/jquery/dist/jquery.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.303:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/raphael.min.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.314:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/node_modules/karma/static/context.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.314:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/src/assets/cmp/js.cookie.min.js?c3a95779bcddbb0eff1aafece75a53295b01124e /
16 03 2017 20:50:32.314:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/js.cookie.min.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.315:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter/src/css/jasmine.css?c9871b8538297ee2479a3223e4b1c8afaa94e162 /
16 03 2017 20:50:32.315:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter/src/css/jasmine.css
16 03 2017 20:50:32.316:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/src/assets/cmp/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js?3b965a36a6b08854ad6eddedf85c5319fd392b4a /
16 03 2017 20:50:32.316:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.336:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/js.cookie.min.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.350:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter/src/css/jasmine.css
16 03 2017 20:50:32.367:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.380:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/src/assets/cmp/bootstrap-switch/dist/js/bootstrap-switch.js?4e734a9596dc5356c708a790e43f5e77db7c8f33 /
16 03 2017 20:50:32.381:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/bootstrap-switch/dist/js/bootstrap-switch.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.381:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/src/assets/cmp/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js?4ad010fe0b62b789365b76833c0008cc0b424618 /
16 03 2017 20:50:32.381:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.381:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/src/assets/cmp/morris.js/morris.js?582e763141f9a6b1490ba8af9b37c7cd95255992 /
16 03 2017 20:50:32.381:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/morris.js/morris.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.381:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/src/assets/cmp/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.js?4a2a7ed5473af5b3561dcb25ec38c33315f775ce /
16 03 2017 20:50:32.382:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.382:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/src/assets/cmp/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js?1988633067079e50c05ac4bf42eb59c97aa96992 /
16 03 2017 20:50:32.382:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.382:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/src/assets/cmp/jquery.blockui.min.js?4d1ff795d8ce96081c46af237b983b02f2b4536d /
16 03 2017 20:50:32.382:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/jquery.blockui.min.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.396:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/bootstrap-switch/dist/js/bootstrap-switch.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.424:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.438:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/morris.js/morris.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.453:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.477:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.490:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/jquery.blockui.min.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.525:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/src/assets/cmp/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.js?da9fd91cafbd5df4c88707484c02e699cde2417f /
16 03 2017 20:50:32.525:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.525:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/src/assets/js/echo.js?27e50d3d619606d504dea199d017743337e0cc43 /
16 03 2017 20:50:32.525:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/js/echo.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.525:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?916005cc407925f4764668d61d04888d59258f5d /
16 03 2017 20:50:32.526:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.526:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js?945a38bf4e45ad2770eb94868231905a04a0bd3e /
16 03 2017 20:50:32.526:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.526:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js?7a813cc290d592e664331c573a1a796192cdd1ad /
16 03 2017 20:50:32.526:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.526:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter/src/lib/html.jasmine.reporter.js?4af523ab7bfaa86c4966fa332c4dc2bd2278b4cc /
16 03 2017 20:50:32.526:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter/src/lib/html.jasmine.reporter.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.538:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/cmp/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.558:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/assets/js/echo.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.579:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.599:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.622:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.642:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter/src/lib/html.jasmine.reporter.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.700:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter/src/lib/adapter.js?9d2c71b931979c6194d209809111ee3a72cf149b /
16 03 2017 20:50:32.700:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter/src/lib/adapter.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.701:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/src/test.ts?8cc3132c0dad1642b9cf3246e9b897d644110f61 /
16 03 2017 20:50:32.701:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/test.ts
16 03 2017 20:50:32.714:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter/src/lib/adapter.js
16 03 2017 20:50:32.732:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Volumes/EXT/Projects/bct/bct_admin/src/test.ts
Chrome 56.0.2924 (Mac OS X 10.12.3) ERROR
  You need to include some adapter that implements __karma__.start method!

Chrome 56.0.2924 (Mac OS X 10.12.3) ERROR
  You need to include some adapter that implements __karma__.start method!

^C16 03 2017 20:51:57.831:DEBUG [launcher]: Disconnecting all browsers
16 03 2017 20:51:58.470:DEBUG [launcher]: Process Chrome exited with code 0
16 03 2017 20:51:58.471:DEBUG [temp-dir]: Cleaning temp dir /var/folders/jb/ckmrwnyj6sl2gqvbzq28l9x40000gn/T/karma-26134570
16 03 2017 20:51:58.509:DEBUG [launcher]: Finished all browsers
```

Comment: What's your file structure? This error is thrown fo various reasons, running command without specifying karma config, syntax errors in preprocessors or the config itself

Comment: I updated my post with the relevant file structure. tests are placed into each subfolder of a class/component/service. for a component that would look like ./src/app/components/some-component/some.component.spec.ts

Comment: I don't see the karma.conf in your file structure.

Comment: Updated file structure again, the karma.conf.js is in the root folder from where the tests are run as well.

Comment: @JanSchuermann have you tried deleting `node_modules` and reinstalling?

Comment: Yes I did that, multiple times already actually, but the problem persists. I also removed all "non-angular-cli" modules from the package.json and installed it, but that didn't change anything as well.

Comment: Have you ever made any progress on this issue? I'm facing something similar (if not the same) right now and I'm at a complete loss...